# Match a pattern and newlines between

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
a
a
a

b
```

I want to match all the `a` letters and newlines between them, i.e.:

```
a
a
a
```

I tried the following pattern: `((?:a\n)*)`, but it matches also the newline after the last `a`.

I would be grateful for including a link to the regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Why not `((?:a\n)*a)`

Comment: You can use: [`(?:^|\n)(?:a\n)*a`](https://regex101.com/r/hB4pT3/1)

Comment: @anubhava It matches the newline before the first `a` too.

Comment: Yes true it will. If your regex platform allows lookbehind then you can use: `(?<=^|\n)(?:a\n)*a` and avoid this or use Casimir's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very different than anubhava's suggestion:

```
 /^((?:a\n)*a$)/m
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tA8gV5/1)

the `m` modifier changes the meaning of anchors `^` and `$` that match the start and end of the line.

Comment: It looks good, but if I had more complicated pattern than just `a`, would I have to copy-paste it too, like this: `/^((?:[some long pattern]\n)*[some long pattern]$)/m`? Is there a solution that follows the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle?

Comment: @Gothdo: No.... (however, depending of the language you use, perhaps you can try to use a formatted string).